# MySQL: Copying rows using SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to copy rows from the same table but am running into an issue where some of the columns I need to select do not match the column count of the copy:

```
INSERT INTO assessment_question (assessment_id, num, `type`, weight, `text`, `range`, attempts_permitted)
SELECT aq.assessment_id, aq.num, aq.`type`, aq.weight, aq.`text`, aq.`range`, aq.attempts_permitted, aq.active, ca.id as ca_id, cs.id as cs_id
FROM assessment_question aq
joins, where clauses, etc...
```

In this case, I do not want to copy the last 3 columns included in the SELECT as I only use them for correlation later in the query.

How is this possible with MySQL?

Comment: If the columns are indeed nullable, then you need to name the fields in the `INSERT` and can set the value to `null` in the `SELECT`, or if there isn't a non-null default set on those columns, just omit them from the `INSERT` and the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case just simply do not include those fields in the select part of the statement.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear originally. I meant to say that the select statement has 3 columns that I do not want to include in the insert. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: @user1392897 In that case just do not include those fields in the select.